# How can I read a text file containing numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have to read different numbers  in  the same line in a text file. How can I pass them to an Array (for each line),  if I don't know how many numbers I have to read?

I thought about reading each number and passing it to an array, until I  find the New Line character. But I have a lot of files, so doing this takes a lot of time.
With this arrays from each file I have to build plots.  Is there any other way?

```
12 43 54 667 1 2 3 1 545 434 6 476
14 32 45 344 54 54 10 32 43 5 6 66
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `dlmread`

Comment: Do the different lines in one single file have different numbers of entries?

Comment: Within 1 file, does each line have the same amount of numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!    With tha data in my txt file I'm going to build a plot. The first line of my text file is the plot's name (for example May 2016 Temperature) . The other 5 lines are only with numbers . Each line has the same amount of numbers. My plot should have the name specified in the first line . The 5th Number Line is the standart deviation. I have to pass 2 of the other Number lines(1÷4) into 2 different arrays and to build the plot with : the Name, the X and Y axis and Standart Deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open each file and read it line by line, then use `textscan(str,'%d')` to convert each line into an array.

Example for one file:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    C = textscan(str,'%d');
    celldisp(C);
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

You would have to run the code for each file, and do something with the array C.

You can read the additional details on the function [textscan](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Answer (score 1):

The way to read ASCII-delimited, *numerical* data in MATLAB is to use [`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), as already suggested by [@BillBokeey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4383032/billbokeey) in a comment. This is as simple as

```
C = dlmread('file.txt');
```

Comment: The problem with `dlmread` is that it creates a matrix, while Era.H's question mentions that each line has an unknown number of elements.

Comment: He/She doesn't mention that each line as a *different* number of elements, just that it is unknown. The example in the question has the same number of elements, thus `dlmread` works fine.